# How can I generate such vector field animation?

Tags: procedural-generation

I want to generate a vector field animation similar to what is shown [at 55s in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB83DpBJQsE&t=55s), it looks a bit like wind in a grass/wheat field, I would like to know what kind of equation / noise generator is used to create this kind of pattern ?
Thank you

Comment: The video has this in the description: https://anvaka.github.io/fieldplay/
Which shows the code for the velocity field and you can get new fields and code by pressing randomize.

Comment: @lightxbulb Thanks, I did check this tool and it's really nice but unfortunately doesn't tell me what may have been used to generate the waving pattern seen in the video. From what I understand field play simulates a particle flow whereas in the video it is the actuel vector field that is being animated.

Comment: You'll need to make the vector field also a function of time. Though I can't say what formulae exactly he used for this specific video.